# Android studio how search into database using multiple words

Tags: android

After i split the sentence into each words (ex. im a boy (*im* *a* *boy*)). now im thinking now if  i can use those splitted words to search the words to my database?

Now idont have any codes , And i dont knwo how to do , can you guys give some hints how i can make it possible?

Comment: What kind of database is it? How are you creating the database?

Comment: Im gonna use a external database, like Sqlite browser

Comment: Use "where" or "%like%" word's in your query to match with table field you want to match with combination of "AND" clouse .

Comment: Flow : Input the a sentence in the edittext then after that , I split the sentences into each words , and now i want to search those splitted words in my database

Comment: SELECT column1, column2, columnN 
FROM table_name
WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]...AND [conditionN];

Comment: `SELECT [Your Field List] FROM [Your Table] WHERE [Your Field] IN ([Comma Separated PARAMETERS])` and add your parameter list to the query (it's a string array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment you are going to use SQL lite . So you can use the "LIKE" option to search.

Sample Query

```
Select * from table where 
  columnname like'%David%' and 
  columnname like '%Moses%' and columnname like'%Robi%'
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: Ahh, so what if idont know the numbers of words im going to search? your code is still applicable with that?  But thanks I have an idea again

Comment: `code` select pos from wordbank where words like '%bahay%' and words like '%aba%' but the it doesnt work , dis is SQLITE browser says "0 rows returned in 1ms from: select pos from wordbank where words like '%bahay%' and words like '%aba%'"

Comment: copy the db file to your pc and use any external application(SQL Lite Manager or SQL Lite Expert Personal) to open db fie and enter the query and check it. I think there is no result match for that query. Let me know your thought.

Comment: i use that query in sqlite browser , but it doesnt work

Comment: It does not work means no value returned or any query mistakes?        Check the following link. It will hep you to understand the LIKE Command 
     https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp